# AWS cloud-config not setting dns-nameservers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, cloud-init

Here is the `cloud.cfg` on my instance (I had tampered it manually when provisioning the `ami` from which I launched the instance)

```
root@ip-10-17-0-121:~# cat /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg | grep -i resol -C 3

# Network configuration for ami
manage_resolv_conf: true

resolv_conf:
  nameservers: ['10.11.4.1']
```

However this is never taken into account given that:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.17.0.2
search eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

I have tried with and without creating the following file

```
# cat /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg
network: {config: disabled}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make my instance obtain my custom dns-nameserver as follows

```
- name: pre_tasks --> Add my custom dns-nameserver
  lineinfile:
   path: /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
   regexp: '^#prepend domain-name-servers'
   line: 'prepend domain-name-servers 10.11.4.1;'
  become: yes
```

However now I am getting the following warning:

```
pkara@ip-10-17-0-35:~$ sudo -i
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-10-17-0-35
```

not accepting my answer until / unless I address this;

**edit_1**: adding this to my `cloud-config.yml` which I am setting as user data did not help much:

```
hostname: localhost
manage_etc_hosts: true
```

**edit_2**: adding this to my `cloud-config.cfg` helped me to address the above `unable to resolve host` problemn

```
bootcmd:
  - echo "127.0.0.1 $(hostname)" >> /etc/hosts
```